# How to work with background tasks in UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I'm developing a UWP app which uses in-process background task to download new GitHub notifications and show them as toast notifications. I'm using MVVM light. I tried In-process background tasks with *TimeTrigger*, everything works as expected when the app is in foreground or minimized. But when the app is closed, the background tasks stop working. After monitoring task manager, I found that the background task launches but is closed immediately just after launching. So i used **ExtendedExecutionSession** to extend the suspension. Still it isn't working. Using Out of the process background tasks resolves the previous problem but introduces a new problem. The GitHub api call failed in the background due to inaccessibility to the app data (GitHub Auth Data) which is required to make the API call.

In short, I have the following problems:

1. In process background tasks do not run in background when the app is closed
2. Out of the process background tasks can share app data (for instance GitHub Auth data in my case) when I make an API call to GitHub using Octokit

I've found these workarounds:

1. Using **ExtendedExecutionSession** with the in-process background tasks
2. Using **Inter process communication** with the out of the process background tasks

My questions are:

1. How and when should I call **ExtendedExecutionSession** in In-process tasks.
2. How to code **Inter-process communication** in order to be able to access the app data from the background app

Note that I've registered the background tasks in **MainPage.xaml.cs**. Here is the code snippet:

```
var syncBuilder = Helpers.BackgroundTaskHelper.BuildBackgroundTask(
                        "SyncNotifications",
                        new TimeTrigger(15, false),
                        internetAvailableCondition,
                        userPresentCondition,
                        sessionConnectedCondition
                   );
syncBuilder.IsNetworkRequested = true;            
syncBuilder.Register();
```

And I overridden the **OnBackgroundActivated** in the **App.xaml.cs**. Here is the code spippet:

```
var deferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
args.TaskInstance.Task.Completed += BackgroundTask_Completed;
var taskName = args.TaskInstance.Task.Name;
switch (taskName)
{
     case "ToastNotificationBackgroundTask":
          await CoreApplication
          .MainView
          .CoreWindow
          .Dispatcher
          .RunAsync(
               CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
               async () =>
               {
                   var toastTriggerDetails = args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;
                   var toastArgs = QueryString.Parse(toastTriggerDetails.Argument);
                        var notificationId = toastArgs["notificationId"];
                   if (!notificationId.IsNulloremptyOrNullorwhitespace())
                   {
                        await NotificationsService.MarkNotificationAsRead(notificationId);
                   }
               });
          break;
     case "SyncNotifications":
          await CoreApplication
          .MainView
          .CoreWindow
          .Dispatcher
          .RunAsync(
               CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
               async () =>
               {                            
                    AppViewmodel.UnreadNotifications = await NotificationsService.GetAllNotificationsForCurrentUser(false, false);
                    await AppViewmodel.UnreadNotifications?.ShowToasts();
               });
          break;
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked if your code is crashing when the foreground app is not running? One thing to keep in mind is that your app does not have a view when it is not running, so if your background task code makes assumptions about having a view it may fail/crash. Specificially in your code I see it depends on CoreApplication.MainView - which may be null during background activation.

Comment: The other thing to check is your deferral. I don't see when/how you are completing it. If it just goes out of scope at the end of the method then it will get marked as complete and the task will immediately exit, before your dispatcher actions had a chance to run to completion. You need to hold on to the deferral until you are actually done with your task. Come to think about it, this is likely the issue you are hitting.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT that was a mistake editing this post. I actually used `deferral.Complete();` at the end of the code.

Comment: I also tried without using `CoreApplication.MainView`and got the same result.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "end of the code". Do you mean end of the method, or after you have actually completed your task? Also have you checked whether or not your code is hitting an exception/crash here?

Comment: No there is no exception thrown when I comment out `CoreApplication.MainWindow`. I've called `deferral.Complete()` at the end of **OnBackroundActivated**  method. All the toasts are shown correctly when the app is running (either on the foreground or minimized or foreground but not focused - the focus is on other app). But the problem occurs when I close the app, Nothing works as expected behavior. After examining the process in the task manager, I got that it just turns as a background process with a background broker. and the bg task run at the right time but with not the expected behavior.

Comment: Note that the exception is handled in **Application_UnhandledException** method in the **App.xaml.cs** and it will show a MessageDialog with the error message.

Comment: You won't be able to show a dialoag when you are background activated. Try logging to a file instead.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Will it be efficient if I chose to use out of the process background task which calls in-process Apps services that actually make an API call to GitHub for **inter-process communication**. If not please suggest me how can i implement inter process communication efficiently. Such that background tasks communicates to the app itself to make API call to GitHub. Is App Service Ling lived? I mean can it run for more than 30 secs? or should I use a Maintenance trigger instead of Time trigger?

Comment: in-proc background task is a good way to go for your scenario, just need to fix the bug in your code :-)  Let me write and answer ...

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But the the reason why I want to implement it with an out of the process background task is that If something goes wrong within the background tasks, the main app shouldn't crassh

Comment: If you have questions about communicating with out-of-proc background tasks, please open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are completing the Deferral too early, i.e. before your asynchronous dispatcher work items had a chance to execute. This happens to work when the app is in the foreground because the process will stay around anyway, but when activated in the background the process will only run until you mark the deferral as complete, meaning it will exit before your task code had a chance to run.

To see what I mean, try a little experiment. Run this code that mimics your current implementation under the debugger and watch in which order the breakpoints are being hit. This will help you realize that you are calling Deferral.Complete before your actual code gets to run:

```
protected async override void OnBgActivated()
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        await PerformTaskAsync();
        Debugger.Break();
    });
    Debugger.Break();
}

private async Task PerformTaskAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Debugger.Break();
    return;
}
```

Now the solution for you is simple, move the Deferral.Complete() call to a place in your code after your task is actually complete. You may have to change the scope of 'deferral' for this and make a class-level variable.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for investing your valuable time. I tried calling the `_deferral.Complete()` in the **Task_Completed** method since I handled **args.TaskInstance.Task.Completed** event handler in the overridden  **OnBackroundActivated**  method. The result is the same. When the app is closed, the background task no longer updates the Toast notification. I've monitored Windows Task Manager and event viewer as well to find out whether the background tasks fails to run OR even run in correct time.

Comment: I found that when the app is running, there is a sub-item under my app named **Background Broker** in the task manager which, I presume, is responsible for running the bg tasks but when i close the app every thing is closed. Perhaps something runs in every 15 mins but that does actually nothing. On the other hand, with out of the process bg tasks, this does not happen. Regardless of whether the app is running, with out of the process bg tasks, there is always background broker in the task manager.

Comment: While the app is opened, my app in listed in Apps category with sub-items: 'MyAppName' and 'Background Broker' and when I close the app, my goes under background processes in the task manager with only one sub-item 'Background Broker'. Which, in my view, implies that out of the process bg tasks always runs in the background and in-proc bg task stops when the app is closed. Otherwise my in-proc code works as expected when the app is in running state regardless of where I'm calling `_deferral.Complete()`..

Comment: There may be other bugs in your code. Without seeing a complete repro of the problem this will be hard to diagnose. I have tested the scenario and it works as expected for me. Here is my test project for your reference: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNq69gcwveq2EYSxG9Jg - if your problem still persists after reviewing my code please share your complete code to repro the problem.

Comment: Here is the GitHub Repo for the project [CodeHub](https://github.com/sicsbd/CodeHub/tree/feature-toast_notification) I'm contributing on

Comment: This is a fairly big project. Can you either provide a simplified repro of the problem, or provide exact steps to reproduce the problem? Take a look at Stackoverflow best practices: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After monitoring Windows Event Viewer, I found that it is logging an information: `Background task for package AalokSingh_2.4.14.0_x64__exh3vkax65k2m with entry point Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.DefaultInProcBackgroundTask did not complete in response to a cancel notification.` To reproduce the issue, you can make a API call to any endpoint and then process the response to show it in the toast and update Send message to update the bindings through MvvmLight Messenger. I'm trying to provide you a sample for that ASAP.

Comment: Thanks @StefanWickMSFT for helping me. Completing the deferral at the right time is one of the solutions. First of all, I have shown the messages with toast instead of Message Dialog from all unhandled exceptions and and background cancellation. I found that as async API call is a long-running operation, it has been being cancelled automatically due to running time limitation in time/maintenance trigger. The I moved the core api calls and background operations inside an ExtendedExecutionSession and now it works correctly when the app is running with no exceptions.

Comment: Finally when I close the app window, the background tasks runs but it shows an exception in the toast: **Object reference is not set to an instance of an object**. It happens when I call any static method from a static class to initiate the api call. @StefanWickMSFT Can you please tell me why the exception has occurred? I don;t understand the cause.

Comment: Can you suggest me any open-source project/sample hosted in GitHub that uses such functionalities so that I can learn more? I referring to... initiating an api call from the background task when the app is closed?

Comment: I had already shared a link to my test app earlier in this thread. What's missing from that sample?

Comment: Can you please update us with the direction you choose in the end? I am trying to do something similar where i fetch the data but still have doubts in UWP alone can fulfill my needs as it have 15 mins limit for time trigger and is not straightforward to work with background processes if i understand this question correctly